# Google Chrome - stalled when using ajax, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

In my home/office it worked fine.

[image]

But yesterday i went to setup this to a customer location where they have dedicated internet. But in there network all my packets are getting lost of delayed and completely the whole thing not working as it was working in my home/office network to the cloud.

I get often Google Chrome > network > Timing > Connection setup = Stalled 14.89s and red line of the URL

[image]

How can i fix it please? I spend several hours with there networking guys but they think its my code causing it? i am very confused now.

```
var maincrawl_timer = null;

function crawl() {
    maincrawl_timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var s1 = $.get(submit_url + '/inbox', {
            action: 'spinbox',
            ousername: main_username,
            status: 'offline'
        }, function(msg) {
            for (drawSixRowOnly in msg.db) {}
        }, 'json');

        s1.always(function() {
            console.log('>>> crawl started. Are you sure its not causing Stalled??????????????????');
            crawl();
        });

    }, 3000);
}

// Boot once
crawl();

// Button used - to receive request
function ackowledge(input1, input2) {
    var chk = input2 + '_' + input1;
    if (search_row(chk) == chk) {
        error_show('Accepted by someone else.');
        return false;
    }

    $('#form1_show').show();
    $('#form1_title').html(input2);
    $.post(submit_url + '/spack', {
        action: 'spack',
        ousername: main_username,
        id: input1,
        kiosk: input2
    }, function(msg) {
        if (msg.result == 'ok') {
            spformid = msg.spformid; // selected: ACknowledge id 
            $('#form1_body').html(msg.form);
        } else {
            $('#form1_body').html('Failed');
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

Comment: Can you access the URL, that is stalled, directly on browser address bar?

Comment: @KevinB: Sir, the server is accepting requests there is no restrictions.

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy: YES from address bar i can open it

Comment: And are you sure that you are not trying to make Cross-Domain call?

Comment: What you have here is a network problem. It is either your client's network/computer, or your network/server. diagnose the problem from that point. Since your client's network people have already ruled themselves out as being the problem, it must be on your end. **(or they are wrong)**

Comment: YES - Cross-Domain call is 100% permitted using Zend Framework:     `$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`

Comment: Sir, i used 4G from there network and it works instantly without any issue. The moment i use there cable internet, often i am having this Stall problem and i seem to fail to resolve it. very confusing me.

Comment: That doesn't change the facts unfortunately.

Comment: Like @KevinB said, i believe it is a network problem specific to your client's environment

Comment: OK - thank you. Is there any windows 8.1 curl tools (like centOS) to see from there network if i crawl the same url in verbose mode to my RHEL 7.

Comment: OK - thank you, i will try to see if all the request arrives in my RHEL 7 accesslogs or not, then its for sure there ISP dropping packets or there router/modem must be broken.

Comment: You could try changing the dns server being used by the browser to google's one. (be sure to change it back!) https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Comment: DNS - we have changed but still slow issue killing our project. Please help.

Comment: Problem i have solved - here is the cake. 1) its never a DNS issue 2) its never a network issue 3) its Javascript, Google Chrome issue. i fixed the Javascript by reducing too many ajax requests. other-wise it was impossible to resolve it.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a cross domain issue restricted by the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)? or is there is a disrepancy in time which would invalidate the ssl requests if the time is too much different from expected. Is a response of any type received from yoru server(use wireshark to monitor packets). is any data sent?(again use wireshark).

Comment: I think it has to do with Google chrome where firefox has solution: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-connections-per-servergoogle

Comment: Why did u call your crawl function on error and success ? try to execute an error within the $.get. Maybe that will help

Comment: Does reading a server log help to find something?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your code that would be causing stalled HTTP traffic. What do the HTTP request/response headers look like in your Chrome dev tools when you try to access the server? Are you getting 403 errors? Try SSHing into the server from your client or ask the network engineers to curl on the server with your client URL. If all this appears to show that the server will accept packets from the client, then perhaps you are sending your packets to the incorrect port or you are not authenticated properly. In the case that you are not authenticating properly, learn about the server's security requirements. You may have to implement Oauth/cookies/Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers to authenticate properly.